# Get Batch File Return Code after sqlcmd Database Backup completes

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, database-backups, sqlcmd

I am currently using a Batch file running on a scheduler that backs up my database (Batch_1) prior to kicking off another batch for processing the data (Batch_2).  I have Batch_2 dependent on Batch_1 completion.  The problem I am running into is Batch_1 is returning as complete before the DB Backup is completed.  It is giving a successful return code once successfully "executed" not "Completed".  This is causing my backup to still be running while Batch_2 kicks off.

Is there some parameter or way (other than sleep timers) to ensure Batch_2 does not kick off prior to Batch_1 fully completing?  Here is the code I have in Batch_1

```
@echo off
echo starting SQL Agent Schedule Job

sqlcmd -S SQLSERVERNAME -E -d MSDB -Q "sp_start_job 
'App:DB_MonthlyBackup_Automation'"

set exitrc=%errorlevel%
if not %exitrc% == 0 goto :exit

set exitmsg=Processing complete

:exit

echo Step: %exitmsg%  RC: %exitrc%
echo finishing Shared Report Schedule Job
exit %exitrc%
```